# Http Mocking with Angular and Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocking, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Mock-file.js

```
exports.httpBackendMock = function(){
  angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E'])
  .run(function($httpBackend){
    mockPeopleData = {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Jennifer",
      "gender": "Female"
    };
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/\api\/1\/people/).respond(mockPeopleData);
  });
}
```

I am getting the `mockPeopleData` from a live page in our application.

Steps to achieve:
*Refresh page > Inspect element > Network tab > XHR tab > Click an end point from the 'Name' section on the left > Then 'Response'*

I am copying that object and using it as 'the thing to mock' in protractor tests.

Spec-file.js

```
var mockModule = require('./Mock-file.js');

describe('testing our mock module', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', mockModule.httpBackendMock);
  });
  it('should find html content', function(){
    expect(browser.isElementPresent(element(by.binding('person.name')))).to
  }); 
});
```

Above we are adding our module, and expecting protractor to find an element containing 'Jennifer' on the page from our mockPeopleData.

index.html

```
<span>{{person.name}}</span>
```

Ideally, protractor will mock our element and later identify it in our tests. Instead, I am getting 'element not found' - and I have confirmed that the element is not there by taking a screenshot during our test.

```
browser.wait(function() {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
          var stream = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/screenshot.png");
          stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
          stream.end();
        }); 
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `browser.addMockModule()` before `browser.get()`? thanks.

Comment: @alecxe yes I am calling `browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8000');` immediately before the `expect` statement

Answer (score 0):

> called `browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8000');` immediately before the expect statement

I suspect this is the problem. You are calling `get()` directly on the driver instance not letting protractor inject things on the fly. Use the `browser` object directly:

```
browser.get("http://localhost:8000");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @alecxe. `browser.driver.get()` is just the vanilla WebDriver object. Our application is manually bootstrapped - so at times this is necessary. In this case, using `browser.get('http://localhost:8000');`, protractor responds with *Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.* But `browser.driver.get`, protractor responds with, *Expected false to be true.*